# How do I make Timidity play MIDIs with only the sine wave instrument?

Tags: software, midi

I have Timidity++ installed with FluidSynth soundfonts. How do I make Timidity play back any MIDI, mapping all instruments to a sine wave instrument (patch 81, bank 2, [according to General MIDI Level 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI_Level_2#Synth_Lead))?

I've tried, e.g., this in the Timidity config file:

```
map gm2 0 19 2 81
```

But it didn't use the sine wave instrument for the particular MIDI file I was playing back (bank 0, patch 19 = "church organ" instrument in that particular file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon [thrig's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/44304/28419):

Download [Sine Wave.sf2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeensyAudio/Wavetable-Synthesis/master/Soundfonts/Sine%20Wave.sf2) and put it in `/usr/share/sounds/sf2/` (or wherever your soundfont directory is). Add to `timidity.cfg` (or the corresponding file it sources with `trysource`):

```
81 %font "Sine Wave.sf2" 2 81 amp=100 pan=0
```

From the `timidity.cfg` manpage:

> number %font file bank prog [key] [options]
>  number %sample
> file [options]
>
> Specifies that the MIDI program number in the current tone bank or
> drum set should be played using the patch file. If *file* is
> SoundFont, the specific instrument with *bank*, *prog*, and *key* is
> taken out by the format of **number %font**. If *file* is linear AIFF
> or WAV sample data, the MIDI program number is specified by the format
> of **number %sample**.

If you'd like to re-map:

> map MapID1 from-bank from-prog to-bank to-prog
>
> The existing tone is assigned as a tone of GS/XG each map. **gm2**, **sc55**, **sc88**, **sc88pro**, **sc8850, xg** and **xgsfx64** can be specified to be *MapID1*.

add

```
map gm2 0 19 2 81
```

to `timidity.cfg`, too.

However, I tried this, and `timidity` still played the original midi with the Square Lead (bank 0, patch 81), not Sine Wave (bank 2, patch 81), instrument.

---

Also, [Musescore](https://musescore.org/en) can edit MIDIs and easily change the voice to "Sine Wave". See: "[using custom SoundFonts in MuseScore](https://musescore.org/en/node/293510)".

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I cannot get `map` to do anything, so without diving through the source code, who knows. However! If you have a soundfont file, the `bank` and `number` configuration entries appear to do the trick via the following in `~/share/timidity/timidity.cfg`:

```
dir /home/jdoe/share/timidity/inst
bank 0
0 %font tabla_drums.sf2 0 0
1 %font tabla_drums.sf2 0 0
...
127 %font tabla_drums.sf2 0 0
```

Where the `/home/jdoe/share/timitidy/inst` directory contains for this example a `tabla_drums.sf2` SoundFont file. This maps test MIDI files to use the tabla drums via:

```
% timidity --config-file=~/share/timidity/timidity.cfg foo.midi
```

However, via the `lspatch.pl` script under the timidity source tree, and the `sf_list` script of the `MIDI::SoundFont` perl module, I can find no bank 2 patch 81 patterns nor soundfont entries, so I'm not sure what would provide it, as it does not appear to be present in timidity 2.13.2 nor via the GeneralUser_GS_1.43-FluidSynth soundfont... (if there is a pattern file with a sine wave, then the `number` configuration would run something like `0 blah.pat` and so forth for all the patch numbers.)

Another option would be to edit the MIDI and alter any `patch_change` events to use a particular instrument, but that's more work, and there may also be bank select events that also need filtering.